# Get cipher mode and padding scheme from existing Cipher

Tags: java, encryption, aes, javax.crypto

I have an existing Cipher, created using

```
Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
```

for which **I'd like to know what cipher mode and padding scheme was automatically chosen**.

---

```
aesCipher.getProvider().getInfo()
```

returns

> SunJCE Provider (implements RSA, DES, Triple DES, AES, Blowfish, ARCFOUR, RC2, PBE, Diffie-Hellman, HMAC, ChaCha20)

which is what the current provider supports. However, there seems to be no information available what method is/was being used for encryption.

Comment: The provider implements all those algorithms. It doesn't tell you which algorithm was just used, or what its parameters were. Unclear why you would think otherwise. `getBlockSize()` returns an integer block size, not a padding scheme. You seem to be looking for [Cipher.getParameters()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#getParameters--), and you don't seem to have consulted the Javadoc.

Comment: @user207421 unfortunately, Cipher#getParameters always returns null.

> Unclear why you would think otherwise
Why I would expect it: One method was used so I'd expect to be able to figure out which was used. I want to pin the method + padding scheme to ensure that underlying changes of the operating system for example have no influence whatsoever.

Comment: Why? Why should the Provider object remember what it last did? This is not a reasonable expectation. You should get your information from the Cipher object itself. It has plenty of methods provided for exactly that purpose. `getAlgorithm()` for example. Try a few, instead of just guessing.

Comment: I would expect a cipher instance to know which algorithm was chosen. Unfortunately, all methods only return information I already know - nothing about the cipher mode. `getAlgorithm()` for example only returns AES. Hence why I created this post.

Comment: Read the manual to see what the defaults are.  Alternatively, try specifying more detail when you create the instance:  `Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES-CBC");` or whatever.  The documentation will tell you what is available.

Comment: Thanks rossum, I know about that. I have previously encrypted the data by just providing `AES` for the instance. Now I want to pin the exact method/pattern scheme without having to try all 136 available services of the provider.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this snippet can answer your question:

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.spec.InvalidParameterSpecException;

public class CipherDetails {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidParameterSpecException {
        System.out.println("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61456475/get-cipher-mode-and-padding-scheme-from-existing-cipher");

        byte[] keyByte = "12345678901234567890123456789013".getBytes("UTF-8");
        SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyByte, "AES");

        //Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");
        //Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);

        // key & algorithm details
        System.out.println("SecretKey Algorithm: " + secretKey.getAlgorithm() + " keylength: " + secretKey.getEncoded().length);
        System.out.println("SecretKey format: " + secretKey.getFormat());
        System.out.println("Cipher Algorithm: " + cipher.getAlgorithm() + " Blocksize: " + cipher.getBlockSize());
        System.out.println("Cipher Parameters: " + cipher.getParameters());
        System.out.println("Cipher Provider: " + cipher.getProvider());
        System.out.println("Cipher Provider getInfo: " + cipher.getProvider().getInfo());
        try {
            System.out.println("Cipher IV: " + bytesToHex(cipher.getIV()) + " IV length: " + cipher.getIV().length);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println("cipher IV: Algorithm does not use an IV");
        }
        try {
            System.out.println("Cipher parameters encoded: " + bytesToHex(cipher.getParameters().getEncoded()));
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println("cipher parameters encoded: not available");
        }
    }

    private static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        for (byte b : bytes) result.append(Integer.toString((b & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

This is the result:

```
SecretKey Algorithm: AES keylength: 32
SecretKey format: RAW
Cipher Algorithm: AES/GCM/NoPadding Blocksize: 16
Cipher Parameters: 
    iv:
[0000: AE 93 E3 D9 72 83 E1 84   D5 FA C4 97              ....r.......
]
tLen(bits):
128

Cipher Provider: SunJCE version 11
Cipher Provider getInfo: SunJCE Provider (implements RSA, DES, Triple DES, AES, Blowfish, ARCFOUR, RC2, PBE, Diffie-Hellman, HMAC, ChaCha20)
Cipher IV: ae93e3d97283e184d5fac497 IV length: 12
Cipher parameters encoded: 3011040cae93e3d97283e184d5fac497020110
```